# AES encryption using openssl

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt using openssl AES encryption function.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <string.h>

const static unsigned char aes_key[]={"passwordpasswor"}; //15 characters + \0
void print_data(const char *tittle, const void* data, int len);

int main() {
unsigned char aes_input[]="#!/bin/bash\necho hello world";
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
memset (iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
unsigned char enc_out[sizeof(aes_input)];
unsigned char dec_out[sizeof(aes_input)];
AES_KEY enc_key,dec_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&enc_key);
AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input,enc_out,sizeof(aes_input),&enc_key,iv,AES_ENCRYPT);
//decryption
memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&dec_key);
AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out,dec_out,sizeof(aes_input),&dec_key,iv,AES_DECRYPT);
//verify
printf("original %s\n",aes_input);
printf("encrypted %s\n",enc_out);
printf("decrypted %s\n",dec_out);
return 0;
}
```

the code produces the following output (with an extra newline between each for clarity):

```
original #!/bin/bash
echo hello world

encrypted ���jv�.)��$I���b�:dmPvTQޜ�#!/bin/bash
echo hello world

decrypted #!/bin/bash
echo hello world
```

I've tried other messages, it seems that the encryption message will show the original message if used with printf.

Comment: First, *stop* trying to send non-printable characters to `stdout`. Your encrypted buffer contains raw octets. not only is it highly likely not displayable on a terminal, it is also potentially not terminated (as you see). What exactly is your *question*, btw?

Comment: Your encrypted string is not terminated with `\0` symbol.

Comment: question is I'd like to hide the original message
I've added \0 and I'm getting the same result

Comment: @AdelAhmed declaring `unsigned char enc_out[sizeof(aes_input)+1]` and doing `enc_out[sizeof(aes_input)] = '\0'` before printing doesn't help?

Comment: actually I manually entered \0 into the string temporarily :D
not sure if this is the way to go

Comment: What, exactly is your problem or question?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to dump non-printable data to a terminal device, and specifically doing so using a library call that expects null-termination. The output of an AES encryption can contain bytes of *any* value (including embedded nullchar values)

You need the following:

- Properly size your output buffer size. By default `AES_cbc_encrypt` uses pkcs padding and will use up to one full additional block for padding data.
- Dump your output using an alternative mechanism, such as a trivial hexdump routine.

Both of the above are done below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <string.h>

static hex_print(const void *pv, size_t len)
{
    static const char alpha[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    const unsigned char *beg = pv, *end = beg+len;

    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
    {
        putc(alpha[(*beg >> 4) & 0xF], stdout);
        putc(alpha[*beg & 0xF], stdout);
    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

const static unsigned char aes_key[]={"passwordpasswor"}; //15 characters + \0
void print_data(const char *tittle, const void* data, int len);

int main() {
    unsigned char aes_input[]="#!/bin/bash\necho hello world";
    unsigned char enc_out[AES_BLOCK_SIZE * ((sizeof(aes_input) + AES_BLOCK_SIZE)/AES_BLOCK_SIZE)];
    unsigned char dec_out[sizeof(aes_input)];
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};

    AES_KEY enc_key,dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input,enc_out,sizeof(aes_input),&enc_key,iv,AES_ENCRYPT);

    //decryption
    memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out,dec_out,sizeof(aes_input),&dec_key,iv,AES_DECRYPT);

    //verify
    printf("original %s\n",aes_input);
    hex_print(enc_out, sizeof enc_out);
    printf("decrypted %s\n",dec_out);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
original #!/bin/bash
echo hello world
e389c96a76d708b42e29b4b4052449f1ffc762db3a646d1650765451de9c1dd0
decrypted #!/bin/bash
echo hello world
```

Note in particular the *last* byte of the encryption. It isn't `00`, which means the `printf` call you were incorrectly using was marching beyond that buffer and into the land of *undefined behavior*. In fact, there are *no* nullchar bytes in that string (it is a different, yet closely-related problem when there *is* an embedded `00` in the *middle* of your data, in which case `printf` would have stopped *prematurely*.

In this case, I can *speculate* (with little value; such is the nature of *undefined behavior*) that the march took `printf` into the next automatic variable on the stack, which was the decrypted array.

Modifying the output sequence to use *all* hex output will demonstrate the difference between plaintext and encrypted data. For example, changing the last three functional lines of your program to:

```
//verify
hex_print(aes_input, sizeof(aes_input));
hex_print(enc_out, sizeof enc_out);
hex_print(dec_out, sizeof(dec_out));
```

will deliver the following output:

```
23212f62696e2f626173680a6563686f2068656c6c6f20776f726c6400
e389c96a76d708b42e29b4b4052449f1ffc762db3a646d1650765451de9c1dd0
23212f62696e2f626173680a6563686f2068656c6c6f20776f726c6400
```

which makes sense. if you walk the bytes (two digits per) in the original and decrypted strings you can see they're (a) equal, (b) not equal to the cipher text, and (c), a little time in an [ascii table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) will show you they are indeed the original text message.

Best of luck.

Comment: I want to write the ecrypted data to a file and later decrypt it though, can that be done with hex dumps?

Comment: @AdelAhmed in that case, use `fwrite`. the hexdump was only done so the display (your output) was readable). If you're instead planning on storing to a file, `fwrite` and `fread` are probably what you want.. Be sure to include `b` (binary) in your `fopen`s.

Answer (score 0):

You have encrypted the terminating `nul` of the string by using the argument

```
sizeof(aes_input)
```

You are consistent, so it gets decrypted too. Unfortunately the encrypted string no longer has a `nul` terminator, since it was encrypted too. So I recommend

```
strlen(aes_input)
```

for the arguments (but not for the string allocation). You must also terminate the two strings `enc_out[]` and `dec_out[]`.

Comment: changing sizeof to strlen resulted in a segmentation fault